# Windows Phone 8 blacklist

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to implement Windows Phone 8 blacklist?
The update gdr2 have this functionality.
But API documentation has no description.

Tell me how you can implement a software reset incoming call.

Comment: What do you mean by reset incoming call? Do you want the ability to intercept an incoming call, to put it on hold or cancel the call?

Comment: cancel call, Black list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Unfortunately the Windows Phone 8 API does not currently give developers access to such functionality.

If you want functionality like this to be included, please vote for it on the WPDev Feedback page: [Link](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1905841-please-allow-readonly-access-to-call-history-and).

Comment: You could try and hack the OS, or plead with MS to give you the API functionality. The former is illegal, the latter would not have a high chance of success.